# How do you list file names based on a keyword?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do you list file names based on a keyword?

```
Dim allFileNames as String() =
    Directory.GetFiles("C:\PDFFiles", "*.PDF", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim filtered As IEnumerable(Of String) = Where(Function(fileName) Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName).Contains("*ts"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my method:

```
''' <summary>
''' Return the files matching the specified file extension
''' and matching the specified keyword in the filename.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Folder">Indicates the directory to search files.</param>
''' <param name="Recursivity">Indicates the subdirectory recursivity mode.</param>
''' <param name="FileExt">Indicates the file extension to match.</param>
''' <param name="KeyWord">Indicates a keyword to match on the filenames.</param>
''' <param name="IgnoreCase">Indicates the CaseSensitivity of the KeyWord match.</param>
''' <returns>System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.IO.FileInfo).</returns>
Private Function GetFiles(ByVal Folder As String,
                          ByVal Recursivity As Boolean,
                          ByVal FileExt As String,
                          ByVal KeyWord As String,
                          Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = False) As List(Of IO.FileInfo)

    Return (
            From File As String
            In IO.Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*" & FileExt, If(Recursivity, 1, 0))
            Where If(IgnoreCase,
                     IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File).ToLower.Contains(KeyWord.ToLower),
                     IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File).Contains(KeyWord))
            Select New IO.FileInfo(File)
            ).ToList

End Function
```

Usage Example:

```
    Dim Files As List(Of IO.FileInfo) =
        GetFiles(Folder:="C:\Windows\System32", Recursivity:=False,
                 FileExt:="dll", KeyWord:="win", IgnoreCase:=True)

    For Each File As IO.FileInfo In Files
        MessageBox.Show(File.Name)
        MessageBox.Show(File.Length)
    Next File
```

> UPDATE:

Just an Overload method:

```
''' <summary>
''' Return the files matching the specified file extension
''' and matching the specified keyword in the filename.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Folder">Indicates the directory to search files.</param>
''' <param name="Recursivity">Indicates the subdirectory recursivity mode.</param>
''' <param name="FileExts">Indicates the file extensions to match.</param>
''' <param name="KeyWord">Indicates a keyword to match on the filenames.</param>
''' <param name="IgnoreCase">Indicates the CaseSensitivity of the KeyWord match.</param>
''' <returns>System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.IO.FileInfo).</returns>
Private Function GetFiles(ByVal Folder As String,
                          ByVal Recursivity As Boolean,
                          ByVal FileExts As String(),
                          ByVal KeyWord As String,
                          Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = False) As List(Of IO.FileInfo)

    ' Set all the file extensions to lower-case.
    FileExts = (
                From FileExt As String In FileExts
                Where Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FileExt)
                Select FileExt.ToLower()
                Distinct
               ).ToArray

    Return (
            From File As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*", If(Recursivity, 1, 0))
            Where FileExts.Contains(IO.Path.GetExtension(File).Substring(1).ToLower)
            Where If(IgnoreCase,
                     IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File).ToLower.Contains(KeyWord.ToLower),
                     IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File).Contains(KeyWord))
            Select New IO.FileInfo(File)
           ).ToList

End Function
```

Usage example:

```
    Dim Files As List(Of IO.FileInfo) =
        GetFiles(Folder:="C:\Windows\System32", Recursivity:=False,
                 FileExts:={"dll", "exe"}, KeyWord:="sys", IgnoreCase:=True)
```